# Distance between permutation and its inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra

I would like to know the maximum of (in term of $n$) 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\sigma(i)-\sigma^{-1}(i)|\leq? \tag{1}
\end{equation}
for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\sigma\in S_{n}$ (Permutation group).

I try to find the reference of equation (1) but I always see $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\sigma(i)-i|$. I am not sure equation (1) was proved by someone. If yes, please give me the reference or proof.

And if there exists the maximum, what are the conditions that the equality holds?

Thank you.

Comment: Every $i$ equals $\sigma(j)$ for some $j$. Then the sum becomes $\sum_{j=1}^n|\sigma^2(j)-j|$. Hope this helps.